# Justify each step with a property, definition or an operation

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

A math expression has changed from one form to another and I need to know what has happened during that step:

1. from **(3x + 10x) + 2y** 
   to **x(3 + 10) + 2y**

we have two different answers: one says it is a result of a distributive operation and another says it is a result of an associative operation.

which one is correct, distributive or associative?

2. from **x(13) + 2y**
   to **13x + 2y**

which one is correct, distributive or commutative?

thanks,

Comment: What are your thoughts on these problems?  We are not here to do your homework for you...

Comment: What do you mean you have two different answers?  From where?  If told you it was because it was a teacup would you have three different answers?

Comment: @Xander, even it is my homework, if you explain it correctly to me, you will help me in my math. That is not a good thing to do? if you don't know the correct answer like me, or you don't want to help other person, why not just ignore it? The fact is that my daughter and I have different answers for these questions. We need the right ones during the weekend. I really appreciate these answers below. They have explained very clearly. We fully understand those concepts now. We are very happy now. Hope you will not angry at those nice people willing to help people no matter what the reasons are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(3x+10x)=(x3+x10)$ by Commutative and $(x3+x10)=x(3+10)$ by distributive.

But also: 
$(3x+10x)=(3+10)x$ by distributive and $(3+10)x=x(3+10)$ by commutative

The same is for the $x(13)$(In this case  we may include that $a+0=a$ and that $a\cdot0=0$ for all $a$)

Associative is only in the case of $f(f(a,b),c)=f(a,f(b,c))$.

For example saying that $(a+b)+c=a+(b+c)$ is by associative: $f(a,b)=a+b$ so $f(f(a,b),c)=(a+b)+c$ that is equal to $a+(b+c)=f(a,f(b,c))$.

Comment: I am new here. I am not able to up vote you. I am sorry. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

On the first one you can factor an x so yes, you can say call out the distributive property. On the second question you are commuting the first term. Remember that multiplication is commutative.

Comment: I am new here. I am not able to up vote you. I am sorry. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Distribution is the property that $a(b+c) = ab + ac$?  (i.e. you are distributing multiplication across a sum).  Distribution goes the other way in that $ab + ac = a(b+c)$.  (i.e. you can factor terms out that have been distributed.)

Association of addition is the property that $(a+b) +c = a+(b+c)$ (i.e. it doesn't matter how you group them)

Association of multiplication is the property that $a(bc) = (ab)c$ (ditto).

Which does $(3x + 10x) + 2y \implies x(3+10) + 2y$ appear to be.  Clearly distributive.

Perhaps there was a term before that $3x + (10x + 2y) \implies (3x + 10x) + 2y$  is associative.

$x(3+10) + 27 \implies x(13) + 27$ is just addition.

And $x(13) + 27= 13x + 27$ is just reversing the order of $13$ and $x$.  That we can reverse order of multiplication is the commutative property of multiplication.

Comment: I am new here. I am not able to up vote you. I am sorry. I really appreciate your help.